# In python Yfinance how to handle case when ticker is TRUE. (TrueCar stock) . Currently throws an error

Tags: python, yfinance

I am using YFinance in Python to download stock price data, and it works very well, but crashes  for when the symbol is TRUE, that is the ticker symbol the stock TrueCar. The code is:

```
 symbols=tickerlist['Ticker']
 resultMostRecent = {}
 successFlag={}
 for index,row in tickerlist.iterrows():
     symbol=row['Ticker']

     thedate=row['Date']
     data = yf.Ticker(symbol)
     startdate=thedate+timedelta(hours=9,minutes=30)
   
     try:
         today_data = data.history(period='1d',interval='1d',start=startdate)
         resultMostRecent[symbol] = round((today_data['Close'][0]),2)
         successFlag[symbol]=True
      except:
         print('error: most recent price'+symbol)
         resultMostRecent[symbol]=None
         successFlag[symbol]=False
         continue
```

The code crashes on the line data = yf.Ticker(symbol) and gives the following error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxx\Pictures\YahooTickers01.py", line 92, in 
data = yf.Ticker(symbol)

```
 File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\yfinance\ticker.py", 
 line 34, in __init__
 super(Ticker, self).__init__(ticker, session=session)

 File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", 
 line 508, in __init__
  self.ticker = ticker.upper()

  AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Suggestions on how to fix. The data is read from an excel file. Inside the excel file, I formatted the Ticker column to be text.

`

Comment: Are the dates you are reading from Excel market business days? Also, in the unit test, are you getting data for 1 day period and 1 day interval?

Comment: The code works for several thousand other tickers, just not this one